# Dynamically selecting a class variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I needed help with the following. So the project is a program in python that manages and manipulates 10 bank accounts that may or may not exist at the time. I was having trouble with one section that involves the transfer of funds. All of the information is stored in a class. The class stores the account number name address and account balance.

```
def transtransfer():
    amount = float(input("Transfer Amount (Integer): "))
    account1 = input("Account you want to transfer funds from (Account number): ")
    account2 = input("Account you want to transfer funds to (Account number): ")

while amount < 0:
    print("Transfer amount must be positive: ")
    amount = input("Transfer Amount: ")
```

The `while` statement is simply a check to make sure they can not input a value below 0. But I need some sort of way to allow the user to dynamically select a class variable for editing for later.

The following code is what I am working with, i am initializing all of the accounts manually by calling the bank class:

```
class bank:
def __init__(self, accnum, accname, accadd, accbal):
    self.accnum = accnum
    self.accname = accname
    self.accadd = accadd
    self.accbal = accbal

def printclass(self):
    print("Account Number: " + str(self.accnum))
    print("Account Name: " + str(self.accname))
    print("Account Address: " + str(self.accadd))
    print("Account Balance: " + str(self.accbal))

def printclassid(self):
    print("Account Name: " + self.accname)
    print("Account Number: " + self.accnum)

acc1 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc2 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc3 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc4 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc5 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc6 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc7 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc8 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc9 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
acc10 = bank('0', '0', '0', '0')
```

Comment: You left out any code that describes the class(es) you are working with.

Comment: You can dynamically access an attribute using `getattr` however I question the design decision to name attributes after what you expect the user to enter. Rather, parse the he input, then call the appropriate method yourself.

Comment: It looks like you're not yet familiar with lists and dicts. You should start using them.

Comment: That is a lot of code and I can't even begin to guess where you have the problem. You may have more luck building a toy program focused on just one problem and work it from there.

Comment: i will make a dummy program to test some things. thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your accounts `acc1`, `acc2`, etc... were in a list called `accounts`. You could then build indexes to those accounts.

```
accounts_by_number = {acc.accnum:acc for acc in accounts}
```

You can now edit numbers dynamically:

```
def transfer(fromacct, toacct, amount):
    try:
        # disallow negative transfers
        if amount < 0:
            print("Bad amount", amount)
            return False
        # validate from has the funds
        f_new = accounts_by_number[fromacct].accbal - amount
        if f_new > 0:
            # calculate new balance
            o_new = accounts_by_number[toacct].accbal + amount
            # commit the transfer
            accounts_by_number[fromacct].accbal = f_new
            accounts_by_number[toacct] = t_new
            return True
        else:
            print("insufficient funds")
            return False
    except KeyError as e:
        print("Bad account number:", e.args[0])
        return False
```

Comment: can you clarify for me as to what the logic in this section is doing?

        f_new = accounts_by_number[fromacct].accbal - amount
        if f_new > 0:
            o_new = accounts_by_number[toacct].accbal + amount
            accounts_by_number[fromacct].accbal = f_new
            accounts_by_number[toacct] = t_new
            return True

Comment: I should have called that "transfer". You don't want to debit one side unit you are sure you can credit the other. The try/except makes sure both accounts exist and the order of the other stuff is to make sure the from has enough money and the to actually exists before doing the work.

Comment: So the best way to do it is to make all of the acc1-acc10 items in a list and loop through all of them setting them to a dictionary with the account number as the index and the account information(the bank class variables) in the data portion? how would i set all of the acc1-acc10 to be items in a list?

Comment: acc1, etc... should never have existed. `accounts = [ bank('0', '0', '0', '0'), bank('0', '0', '0', '0') ]` but notice you already have  a bug: you aren't using unique account numbers.